# How to authenticate Shopware 6 <base-app-url> correctly

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

With the [Admin SDK](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/getting-started/installation) it's possible to further enrich the administration in Shopware 6. As in the installation guide for apps stated, an entry point (base-app-url) needs to be provided in the manifest file of an app.

Since every request needs to be authenticated properly, this GET request also needs authentication. However, I am not able to authenticate this one in the same way as I am successfully doing it with the GET request from [modules](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/administration/add-custom-modules#overview).

The base-app-url request looks the following (in my case with some [custom] entity privileges):

```
http://localhost:3000/sdk?location-id=sw-main-hidden&privileges=%7B%22read%22%3A%5B%22language%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22create%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22update%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22delete%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%7D&shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045964&sw-version=6.4.18.0&sw-context-language=2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b&sw-user-language=de-DE&shopware-shop-signature=e7b20a46487046a515638f76c6fadab6b1c749ea4a8ac6e7653527e73ba18380
```

The shop has the following data

```js
Shop {
  _id: 'sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K',
  _url: 'http://localhost:8888',
  _secret: '3c5a2f031006791f2aca40ffa22e8febbc8a53d8',
  _apiKey: 'SWIAB2PVODCWSLZNDMC5ZM1XWA',
  _secretKey: 'VnNwM0ZOMnN1Y05YdUlKazlPdlduWTdzOHhIdFpacjVCYkgzNEg'
}
```

I am currently authenticating my modules like the following (Node.js):

```js
const SHOPWARE_SHOP_SIGNATURE = 'shopware-shop-signature';

export function authenticateGetRequest(req: Request, shop: Shop): void {
    // e7b20a46487046a515638f76c6fadab6b1c749ea4a8ac6e7653527e73ba18380
    const signature = getSignatureFromQuery(req);

    verifySignature(shop.secret, removeParamsFromQuery(req), signature);
}

function getSignatureFromQuery(req: Request): string {
    if (!req.query[SHOPWARE_SHOP_SIGNATURE]) {
        throw new Error('Signature is not present in request!');
    }

    return req.query[SHOPWARE_SHOP_SIGNATURE] as string;
}

function removeParamsFromQuery(req: Request): string {
    // Some code
    // Returns following string - Does neither work for base-app-url nor for module GET requests:
    // 'shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045964'

    // If the string follows this pattern, it works only for modules:
    // shop-id={id}&shop-url={url}&timestamp={ts}&sw-version={v}&sw-context-language={cl}&sw-user-language={ul}
}

function verifySignature(secret: string, message: string, signature: string): void {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(message).digest('hex');

    if (hmac !== signature) {
        throw new Error('Signature could not be verified!');
    }
}
```

However the base-app-url cannot be verified correctly and the "Signature could not be verified!" error is thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?

**More info:**

Additionally I added a GET request for a module where everything is working:

```
http://localhost:3000/faq?shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045963&sw-version=6.4.18.0&sw-context-language=2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b&sw-user-language=de-DE&shopware-shop-signature=0f0889c9e8086c6c3553dc946a01f2ef27b34cd1c55b0c03901b6d8a6a9b6f53
```

The resulting string can be verified:

```
shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045963&sw-version=6.4.18.0&sw-context-language=2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b&sw-user-language=de-DE
```

Try out following code in some [php sandbox environment](https://onlinephp.io/):

```php
<?php

$message = 'shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045963&sw-version=6.4.18.0&sw-context-language=2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b&sw-user-language=de-DE';
$secret = '3c5a2f031006791f2aca40ffa22e8febbc8a53d8';
$signature = '0f0889c9e8086c6c3553dc946a01f2ef27b34cd1c55b0c03901b6d8a6a9b6f53';

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $secret);

if (!hash_equals($hmac, $signature)) {
    echo 'Signature not valid';
} else {
    echo 'Signature valid';
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Express decodes the query strings automatically with `req.query` depending on your express configuration. Keep in mind to validate the hmac with encoded query params as they are passed from shopware.

In my case the only difference where the decoded privileges and they looked like this:

```
&privileges={"read":["language","ce_atl_faq_group_faqs","ce_atl_faq_group","ce_atl_faq"],"create":["ce_atl_faq_group_faqs","ce_atl_faq_group","ce_atl_faq"],"update":["ce_atl_faq_group_faqs","ce_atl_faq_group","ce_atl_faq"],"delete":["ce_atl_faq_group_faqs","ce_atl_faq_group","ce_atl_faq"]}
```

But they need to look like this:

```
&privileges=%7B%22read%22%3A%5B%22language%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22create%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22update%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22delete%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%7D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`QuerySigner`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Hmac/QuerySigner.php#L41), this is how the signature is generated on the side of Shopware with the actual arguments:

```php
hash_hmac(
  'sha256', 
  'location-id=sw-main-hidden&privileges=%7B%22read%22%3A%5B%22language%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22create%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22update%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22delete%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%7D&shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045964&sw-version=6.4.18.0&sw-context-language=2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b&sw-user-language=de-DE', 
  'VnNwM0ZOMnN1Y05YdUlKazlPdlduWTdzOHhIdFpacjVCYkgzNEg'
);
// 8034a13561b75623420b06fb7be01f20d97556441268939e9a5222ffec12215a
```

Given on your side you remove the `shopware-shop-signature` query param **AND** that the secrets are equal on both sides, you should be able to regenerate the matching signature.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const message = 'location-id=sw-main-hidden&privileges=%7B%22read%22%3A%5B%22language%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22create%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22update%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%2C%22delete%22%3A%5B%22ce_atl_faq_group_faqs%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq_group%22%2C%22ce_atl_faq%22%5D%7D&shop-id=sbzqJiPRrbHAlC2K&shop-url=http://localhost:8888&timestamp=1674045964&sw-version=6.4.18.0&sw-context-language=2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b&sw-user-language=de-DE';
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'VnNwM0ZOMnN1Y05YdUlKazlPdlduWTdzOHhIdFpacjVCYkgzNEg').update(message).digest('hex');
// 8034a13561b75623420b06fb7be01f20d97556441268939e9a5222ffec12215a
```

So in theory your code looks fine. Verify that the query string matches exactly. Things to check:

- Maybe your node server decodes the url entities unwantedly?
- Does your node serve escape special characters in the query string?
- Do the secrets match on both sides?

To consider additionally:

Consider to just point the `base-app-url` to a static page outside of the scope of your app server instead. As that page will be loaded inside an iframe, you can use client side javascript to read the query parameters and, only if necessary, make requests to your app server using the credentials from inside the iframe. Keep in mind you really only need the authentication if you need to handle personalized data, otherwise you might as well serve static assets without the need for authentication.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @dneustadt! The naming of the constant ```SHOPWARE_SHOP_SIGNATURE_HEADER``` is a little unfortunate. As a matter of fact it is the 'shopware-shop-signature' since it is also used in the request header in those other requests, as you already stated. I updated my question in this regard and added the constant. I also added a comment to ```const signature = getSignatureFromQuery(req);``` and it is correctly fetching the signature from the query params as the function name already indicates. So the issue has to be somewhere else, I think.

Comment: As for your second comment: It may be that I have a comprehension issue here but since I'd like to integrate a custom cms element that needs data fetching from my custom entity I think authentication is mandatory. My app is currently built in a way that it is intercepting every iframe GET request and authenticating it. Afterwards I am storing the admin bearer token in session and reusing it in my modules and also later on in my cms element in order to fetch the corresponding data. I am open for every further suggestion, thank you so far!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It looks like everything should be present for the authentication. It's just that there is actually an query parameters it seems. I updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that and it does not work. I updated my answer with new ```timestamps``` and new ```shopware-shop-signature``` for the base-app-url. I also added some info for a module GET request and some php code for clarification. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: So [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Hmac/QuerySigner.php#L41) is where the signature is signed in platform. There are actually three more query params to be expected. I updated my answer. So it looks like params `location-id` and `priviliges` need to be removed to achieve parity. The modules use the same methods as the hidden iframe for the `base-app-url`. Sorry to not be of help since you seemingly already tried that. With the php-based `AppBundle` it worked locally. Maybe consider creating an [issue ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/).

Comment: Okay, thank you so far, that's what I thought. I will create an issue ticket then. So I think I have to omit authentication in this case? Since the base app url also includes all the JS needed for my cms element I don't have an option to verify the signature server side anymore. Therefore my app fetches an API token based on the shop id that is passed in the query, which could lead to a security breach if someone passes a correct shop id. Maybe you have a recommendation here? Reminder: My cms element will be based on custom entity data which needs admin api calls.

Comment: I think I'm getting what you're going for now. You're trying register a custom cms element, though not a generic one, that would be the same for every customer, but specific to each customer based on an API token. Is that correct? In that case I understand your concern. You should then absolutely authenticate the user. If you do have a local installation of Shopware, maybe check where the signature is signed in Shopware (linked above) and debug how the generation differs to yours. There has to be a difference in how the query is parsed or some other minor abnormity.

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I created a module where the shop owner can create faqs (custom entities) and link them in a cms element in order to display them in the storefront where ever they like to. That's what I am trying to achieve. I will take a deeper dive into the Shopware QuerySigner and try my best. However, I can't think of any difference, since it's working for the modules and using the exact same function for signing the uri.

Comment: So I did some debugging. Actually you were initially right. You just remove the `shopware-shop-signature` query param and that's it. All others like `privileges` should stay. I updated with a few more theories where this could've gone wrong. Since this doesn't happen with auth requests for modules, maybe it has something to do with the url encoding of. the privileges, which seem to be exclusive to the `app-base-url`. Authentication works with a php based app server, so I'm grasping at straws here.

Comment: There we go! My express server decodes the query params automatically. In this case the privileges varied from the signed uri from shopware. Appreciate the effort and kindness. Thank you! I updated my question with the solution.